Couldn't resolve the package 'ffi' in 'package:ffi/ffi.dart' (using FFI in a Flutter plugin tuto)
Context :
I would like to create a FFI Plugin Flutter and I follow this official google tuto for doing that : Using FFI in a Flutter plugin
Technical info :

Windows 11
Flutter 3.19.1
clang 16.0.4 (LLVM installed and provided into PATH system)

return error after this command :

cd example
flutter run -d windows

error :

Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...


CUSTOMBUILD :
error : Couldn't resolve the package 'ffi' in 'package:ffi/ffi.dart'.
[C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\ffigen_app\example\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../lib/ffigen_app.dart(3,8): error G832450DD: Not found:
'package:ffi/ffi.dart'
[C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\ffigen_app\example\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../lib/ffigen_app.dart(42,9): error GC9768DF9: Undefined name
'malloc'.
[C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\ffigen_app\example\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../lib/ffigen_app.dart(31,29): error GE5CFE876: The method
'toNativeUtf8' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
[C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\ffigen_app\example\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5):
error MSB8066: la build personnalis�e de
'C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\ffigen_app\example\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\2133b62afd0dee54b370c45418a7c00f\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\ffigen_app\example\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\6286011a556565967b6192c6afee09a7\flutter_assemble.rule'
s'est arr�t�e. Code�1.
[C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\ffigen_app\example\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...
7,5s Error: Build process failed.

Explain :
I follow all the tuto code and copy/paste into my project without another personnal change. also the 3 DuckTape file are copied into src/. For convenience I don't duplicate code example that exist into the link shared begin. But share the main.dart entry file for example test application flutter :
import 'package:ffigen_app/ffigen_app.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const String jsCode = '1+2';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Duktape duktape;
  String output = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    duktape = Duktape();
    setState(() {
      output = 'Initialized Duktape';
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    duktape.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 25);
    const spacerSmall = SizedBox(height: 10);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Duktape Test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(
                  output,
                  style: textStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                spacerSmall,
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Run JavaScript'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    duktape.evalString(jsCode);
                    setState(() {
                      output = '$jsCode => ${duktape.getInt(-1)}';
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Did you add ffi as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file?  Did you run flutter pub get afterward?

Thank you. The tutorial and the generate example project forget to notice this addons in pubspec.yaml ;). You can write response and I after validate this
